# Excel VBA - Loop through recordset

Tags: excel, recordset, vba

I have an issue when looping through a recordset; here is the code:

```
    Dim query as String
    query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE " & filter

    ' Declare variables'
    Dim objMyConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim objMyCmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim objMyRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim objRst As ADODB.Recordset

    Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command
    Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

    'Open Connection'
    objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDB;User ID=test;Password=test"
    objMyConn.Open

    'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
    Set objMyCmd.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
    objMyCmd.CommandText = query
    objMyCmd.CommandType = adCmdText

    'Open Recordset'
    Set objMyRecordset.Source = objMyCmd
    objMyRecordset.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    objMyRecordset.CursorType = adOpenStatic
    objMyRecordset.Open

    Dim FindRecordCount As Integer
    If objMyRecordset.EOF Then
        FindRecordCount = 0
    Else
        objMyRecordset.MoveLast
        FindRecordCount = objMyRecordset.RecordCount ' In this case it returns 4
    End If

     Do Until objMyRecordset.EOF = True
        ' Get variables

        ...

        ' Move to next Record
        objMyRecordset.MoveNext
     Loop
```

When I check how many rows has the recordset , it returns 4, but goes only once through the loop. In this case, it should loop 4 times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used `movelast` before the loop so you'll need to `movefirst` if you want to actually iterate all the records.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write "EOF=true" the "EOF" formula is true in exactly the same situations :)